# Can't log in with Google in Meteor application

Tags: meteor, oauth, google-oauth

For testing, I have made a super simple meteor application which allows a user to log in with Google.

main.html:

```
<head>
    <title>OAuth test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    {{> user}}
    {{> loginButtons}}
</body>
<template name="user">
    {{user}}
</template>
```

main.js:

```
Template.user.helpers({
    user: function() {
        var user = Meteor.user() || "Cake";
        return JSON.stringify(user);
    }
});
```

I have the  `accounts-ui` and `accounts-google` packages installed, and google login configured with clent ID, client secret, allowed JS origins and redirect URL.

Clicking the "Login with Google" button in loginButtons brings up the popup where I should enter my username and password, and asks me if it's ok for my application to see my email address and basic profile info. Clicking "Allow" to this briefly shows the web page "http://myapp.example.com/_oauth/google" with the text "Login completed. ..." before closing the window. However, the `user` template still prints just "Cake", and I am not logged in. There are no entries in the users collection in the database.

The meteor console prints this:

```
W20151005-10:01:46.344(2) (oauth_server.js:71) Unable to base64 decode state from OAuth query: undefined
W20151005-10:01:46.346(2) (oauth_server.js:71) Unable to base64 decode state from OAuth query: undefined
W20151005-10:01:46.346(2) (oauth_server.js:398) Error in OAuth Server: Failed to complete OAuth handshake with Google. failed [400] {   "error" : "invalid_grant" }
```

Any idea what might be wrong? The only thing I can think of is that my app runs on HTTP, not HTTPS, in which case the error message is pretty crappy...

PS:
While writing this question, I installed `accounts-github` and configured that too. The result is pretty much the same:

```
W20151005-10:49:38.748(2) (oauth_server.js:71) Unable to base64 decode state from OAuth query: undefined
W20151005-10:49:38.750(2) (oauth_server.js:71) Unable to base64 decode state from OAuth query: undefined
W20151005-10:49:38.750(2) (oauth_server.js:398) Error in OAuth Server: Failed to complete OAuth handshake with GitHub. bad_verification_code
```

Comment: did you found out what the problem was? I have the same issue

Comment: Nope... Still no clue. Switching to HTTPS didn't work

Comment: any one solve this?

Comment: Nope. Although I haven't tried since I asked the question

Comment: thanks. Yep IBM Connection does not support "state" and it's throwing the error